# Override implement methods in Scala IDE does not work

Tags: eclipse-luna, scala-ide

I am using Scala IDE on Mac (Build id: 4.4.1-vfinal-2016-05-04T11:16:00Z-Typesafe) with Scala 2.11.8. I have a trait defined as below:

```
package services
trait UserSignupService {
  def signupUserByCellphone(cellphone: String) : Future[Boolean]

  def isExistingUser(providerId: String, providerKey: String): Future[Boolean]
  def createUser(providerId: String, providerSignupToken: String)
  def verifySignupToken(providerId: String, providerSignupToken: String): Future[Boolean]
}
```

and a class:

```
package services.impl
@Singleton
class UserSignupServiceImpl extends UserSignupService {

}
```

When I press `CMD-3` and choose `override implement methods` I do not see the methods for the trait defined above. I only see methods from `java.lang.object`.

`Build automatically` is selected and enabled. I also tried cleaning the project but it just doesn't work.

[image]

If I type in the method name and press `ctrl-space` it gives me the correct suggestion:

[image]

What's going on? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I found the answer. The feature is not supported in Scala IDE. As per [this post in google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/G_PDZLiEVPo)

> "This feature "override/implement methods" is a feature provided by
>   the Java editor, it has no knowledge about Scala. Since the Scala
>   editor inherits functionality from the Java editor, this functionality
>   is shown. We could probably override the implementation with our own
>   but so far we didn't. By pressing CMD-1 (the key combination for quick
>   assists), you should get a list with methods to implement. This is a
>   little bit more cumbersome but works."